# Get columns to stretch entire width of the table

Tags: java, css, vaadin, column-width

I'm working in Java using the Vaadin framework.

I have a table with 14 columns. My problem is that that there's a small gap to the right of the last column, like the beginning of a new column that shouldn't be there..

The image shows the problem:

[image]

I've tried solving it with using column expand ratio on the last column, but this makes it abnormally big..

Do any of you know of a property you can use, CSS or Java, that makes the columns stretch over the entire width of the table without causing large column disproportion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known issue, it was closed already [Ticket #6677](http://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/6677)

Comment: Ohh.... well that's a bit annoying.. =\ And it doesn't look like it's been solved either, right?

Answer (score 0):

If you set your table to fullsize that should probably close the "gap".

```
YourTable.setSizeFull();
```

I gues you ahve your table in a layout. Set this layout margin to false and also remove spacing.

Comment: I don't use setMarging or setSpacing.. and setSizeFull() doesn't help.. =\

Comment: I would think that there's probably some CSS parameter that has to be set